# How does the id numbering with SQL CREATE VIEW work in Android?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-studio, cursor, sql-view

**How does the id numbering with CREATE VIEW work in Android?**

Will the primary key (id) be auto generated regardless or will I run into errors?
(I will be attempting to load this view into a cursor loader.)

---

***Code to create my transactions table:***

```
public static final String TABLE_TRANSACTIONS = "transactions";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PAYEE = "payee";
public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String COLUMN_MONTH = "month";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sqlQueryTransactions = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PAYEE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_AMOUNT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_MONTH + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(sqlQueryTransactions);
}
```

***A Sample of the Table is as follows:***

```
id  payee       amount  month    
1   Tom         90      March
3   Tom         66      April
4   Tom         89      May
10  Jasmine     125     April
11  Nancy       151     March
12  Jasmine     175     April
13  Nancy       152     April
```

---

***The VIEW I want to create and use to display in a listview is:***

```
payee   March   April   May
Tom     90      66      89
Jasmine --      300     --
Nancy   151     152     --
```

***This VIEW will be generated with the following SQL Query:***

```
SELECT `payee`
    , SUM(CASE WHEN `month` = 'March' THEN `amount` END) AS `March`
    , SUM(CASE WHEN `month` = 'April' THEN `amount` END) AS `April`
    , SUM(CASE WHEN `month` = 'May' THEN `amount` END) AS `May` 
  FROM `transactions`
  GROUP BY `payee`;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "ID numbering"? The ID column is a column like the others, and it's not part of this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your own layout and  custom `BaseAdapter` or `CursorAdapter` then you will not run into errors,

but if you are using  android provided layout( `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`) and adapter like(`SimpleCursorAdapter`)  ,then you will run into errors.

if you are not bother about the _id to display or any operator base on it then simply add the column in your query and use the default layout of android and adapter too.

like this based on your need you can create your view

```
create view payee_of_MAM as SELECT _id,payee,
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'March' THEN amount END) AS March,
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'April' THEN amount END) AS April,
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'May' THEN amount END) AS May
  FROM transactions
 GROUP BY payee;
```

or use query only like

```
SELECT _id,payee,
           SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'March' THEN amount END) AS March,
           SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'April' THEN amount END) AS April,
           SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'May' THEN amount END) AS May
      FROM transactions
     GROUP BY payee;
```

so as per this you will get the primary key out like this

```
_id    payee    March    April    May  
12     Jasmine           300    
13     Nancy    151      152    
4      Tom      90       66       89
```

and you can use the default layout of android and the adapter by simply pass the cursor.

but the _id will be as per the last entry of the records in your table

Comment: This does answer my question. As a followup, Does the primary key auto-update like the amounts do? If you say the id is of the last entry, then when a new entry is added to the transactions table does the id also update or stay the same?

Comment: @Ni Yao,it will update the _id automatically  in view as well as in raw query  when u execute it